# Custom jQuery function not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have written one custom paremeterized jquery function for fadein and fade out. That function works fine in IE but not in firefox. 
The function is :

```
jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn = function(newDiv) {
    var openDiv = newDiv;

    return $(openDiv).fadeIn();
};

<input type="radio" name="doc3" value="independentCall" class="radioButton" id="indMetaCalls1" onClick="jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn(indCallDetailsDoc1);" />
```

Comment: Just edited your code, shruti. Take a look at the formatting tools next time you post a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are refereing to an element as if it is a member of the windows object. Only IE puts elements in the windows object, so that doesn't work in any other browser.

Use the JQuery object to get a reference to the element:

```
onClick="jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn($('#indCallDetailsDoc1'));"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have javascript enabled in FireFox?

If so, can you show the markup for 'indCallDetailsDoc1'?

Also, why don't you use 'newDiv' directly, instead of copying it into 'openDiv' first?

Answer (score 0):

Try Changeing:

```
onClick="jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn(indCallDetailsDoc1);"
```

to:

```
onClick="jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn(this);"
```

Comment: That was my original thought, then I realised that this would result in the function being passed a reference to 'indMetaCalls1' instead of 'indCallDetailsDoc1'

Answer (score 0):

What is "indCallDetailsDoc1" and why do you call functions using jQuery.fn.dcFadeIn()? You cannot call plugin functions like this.

Please consider reading this page to learn write jQuery plugins:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring